# set imageview corner radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I tried most of the workaround to set the corner radius of a`imageview` found in a cell.

However, it still displays a box. How can i resolve this ?

```
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"def.png"];
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=cell.imageView.frame.size.width/2;
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth=3.0f;
cell.imageView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the result ?

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue using `clipsToBounds` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `masksToBounds` by `clipsToBounds`

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width/2
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES
```

make sure that you have the correct width in `cell.imageView.frame.size.width` for example if you use autolayout for the width of the `UIImageView` you need to move your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` after width calculation

> A view can optionally limit the drawing of its subviews so that any
>   parts of them outside the view are not shown. This is called **clipping**
>   and is set with the view’s `clipsToBounds` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import `QuartzCore` then using layer property of UIImageView like this:

```
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im think the cell overrides the imageView. 
Try pasting that code in the `layoutSubviews` method or add a second imageView to the cell.

In code it would look like this for the layoutSubviews option:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"def.png"];

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=cell.imageView.frame.size.width/2;

    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth=3.0f;

    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    cell.imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}
```

And for a second imageView like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"def.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2;
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;   
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;   
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;   
imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;   
[self addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: Which part do you mean, pasting in layout subviews or a second imageView?

Comment: Both methods actually.

Comment: @Illep I updated my answer. Please check if one of them works.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing clipsToBounds statement.

```
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Add this and let me know what is the result...

If this don't work, try with `cell.clipsToBounds = YES;`

For sure, it will work...